# a very hard result to foreach in php

Tags: php

`$content` is an arry. when i `print_r($content)`  the result is too long. now i

```
echo $fenlei=$content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
```

the result of `$fenlei` is `java`. but there maybe many values of $fenlei. eg:

```
$content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
$content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][1]['taxonomy_term']->name;
$content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][2]['taxonomy_term']->name;
......
```

how to loop out the

```
  $content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][1]['taxonomy_term']->name;
    $content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'][2]['taxonomy_term']->name;
```

value. it too hard for me. :)

Comment: Can you please provide some array hierarchy of the output that you are getting initially from the array using `print_r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the common code and foreach next:

```
$common = $content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'];

foreach($common as $key => $value){
    echo "{$key}: " . $value['taxonomy_term']->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out large arrays that are difficult to read you can try:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';
```

It makes arrays a little more pretty.